# Tracking usage stats of specific react component

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to integrate a feature that lets me track how long users spend in a specific react component (basically a section of the website). The website is build with react + nodejs + mysql. The only solution I can think of, is to send a post request for every minute a person spends in the component (by running a function in intervals when the component is loaded).

Is there a better way to achieve this, that doesn't involve 1000s of requests every minute? I don't want to track the statistics side-wide, only in a specific component.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you really want to track at component level? or do you mean page level?

Comment: Can you please provide more details as to what you mean by “spend in the component” and describe the actions the user performs when considered _in_ the component?

Comment: What about getting the time reference when the component mounts and send a POST request in the componentWillUnmount?

Comment: Celso, yes that is a very nice suggestion and probably the solution I will go for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TYou could use react lifecycle methods to start timer and then send post on unmount
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Example something like this I have not tested code

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
                  start: new Date(),
                  end: new Date()};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    postTimeToApi(this.state.start, this.state.end);
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      end: new Date()
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.end.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Or maybe

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
                  start: new Date()};
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    const end = new Date();
    postTimeToApi(this.state.start, end);
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.start.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```